# celery - set different number of workers for different queues

Tags: heroku, celery

I have a project with lots of Celery tasks, and one of the tasks must be executed only one at a time (it is a request to a 3rd party API which disallows several concurrent connections).

I can achieve this by starting a separate celery process with a separate queue and a concurrency of 1.

Regular celery process:

```
celery -A sourcery worker -Q default -c 4
```

A separate single-worker process:

```
celery -A sourcery worker -Q separate_queue -c 1
```

But I am on Heroku, and I will be billed doubly for spinning up two processes instead of one. So, is there a way to achieve it with a single Celery process?

Comment: implement at the app layer, with a semaphore, is much simpler to me.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to do this.

I had a similar issue where I had a 3rd party API which only allowed one concurrent connection. I ended up running two separate dynos on Heroku.

Somebody did request this feature, but it has not been implemented: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1599

Edit:

There is something called celery-multi that could be worth looking into:

[Celery - run different workers on one server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5463241/celery-run-different-workers-on-one-server)

I'm not sure it's Heroku compatible though, let me know if you try!